# Find the address of the 2nd element of a list in Python

Tags: python, pointers

First, this question is just for better understanding of Python's memory management and I am aware that the usage of pointers goes against the philosophy of Python. But I am just wondering if we can do it.

In C, if my understanding is correct, an array variable is just a pointer pointing to the first memory block in a series of blocks. That is to say, we can do all the following:

1. print the pointer's address
2. print the pointer's value
3. find a pointer's value from the pointer's address
4. find the address of the 2nd element of the array by adding the block size (say, 32) to the memory address of the 1st element of the array.
5. print the value of the 2nd element of the array even if we only know the memory address of the 1st element in the array.

(Please also correct me if the foregoing points are wrong)

My question is, can we achieve something similar in Python? As I am aware, we can:

1. find the memory address of a variable with id() (well let's say we stick to CPython);
2. If we know the memory address of a variable, we can find its value with the following code

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> var = 10
>>> address = id(var)
>>> print(address)
140654547704400
>>> print(ctypes.cast(address, ctypes.py_object).value)
10
```

However, this approach only works if we are dealing with a "simple" variable, say, an integer. If I declare a list and call id():

```
>>> arr = [1, 1.414, 2.718, 3.141]
>>> id(arr)
140654545282880
>>> id(arr[1])
140654545480880
>>> id(1.414)
140654545480880
```

What I will get from `id(arr[1])` is the address of 1.414, instead of the address of the 2nd element of the list `arr`. What I want to get is something like 140654545282912 = id(arr) + 32.

So the question is, will it be possible for us to find the address of the 2nd element of a list, instead of the address of the variable it references to in Python?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic won't work in python. Python is not C/C++. Python lists are not like C/C++ arrays.

Comment: @rdas sure...simply by reading their names anyone will notice Python and C/C++ are just total different...but this does not solve my question...

Comment: Yes, because what you're trying is simply not possible. The reason is because Python != C/C++. Not just in name. But also in how they expose memory. What arrays/lists look like in those languages. How they handle memory references/pointers. If you go deeper than just reading the names of languages & read up on how they work you will find the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: sure, you answer is very informative. In the past I thought Python and C/C++ are different in name only and I thought they are identical in terms of memory management etc so I come up with such a silly question. Now I know that Python != C/C++, very very helpful insight. I should have selected your comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, everything is an object, even primitive data types like `int`. In case of a `list` this will be a [PyListObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html#c.PyListObject) that has the following [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L9-L26):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

As you can see in the comment, `ob_item` structure member holds pointers to the elements of the list.

In summary, a list in Python is an object and it's not equivalent to arrays in C where the name of an array can be used as a pointer to the first element in the array so you can do pointer arithmetic.

**Update: Tue 21 Sep 14:46:55 UTC 2021**

You can use the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module to inspect the underling `PyObject` structure:

**test.py:**

```
import ctypes
import sys

lst = ["red", "blue", "green"]


class PyListObject(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ob_refcnt", ctypes.c_long),
        ("ob_type", ctypes.c_void_p),
        ("ob_size", ctypes.c_long),
        ("ob_item", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)),
        ("allocated", ctypes.c_long),
    ]


def main():
    pylist_obj = PyListObject.from_address(id(lst))

    for idx, s in enumerate(lst):
        addr = pylist_obj.ob_item[idx]
        s_mem = ctypes.string_at(addr, sys.getsizeof(s))

        print(idx, s_mem[-len(s) - 1 : -1].decode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py 
0 red
1 blue
2 green
```

**References:**

- [Python string object representation](https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2020/09/python-string-object-representation/)

Comment: Hi @HTF, revisiting this question after a few months--gets a few extra thoughts: (1) I guess **ob_item is a pointer that points to a pointer? (2) This is the definition of a Python list in C. However, in Python I guess I cannot simply do something like: PyListObject.ob_item? (i.e., when using Python, I cannot delve into the C-level details and read the internals of my python list?)

Comment: `1.` Yes, `2.` see my update: `Tue 21 Sep 14:46:55 UTC 2021`

Comment: Thanks for the very informative update! I believe ctypes.Structure is Python's emulation of a C struct {}? But where do `ob_refcnt` and `ob_type` come from? I checked this link: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/object.h but seems these two variables are not defined even here?

Comment: (can't edit the previous comment) I guess `ob_refcnt` and `ob_type` are two variables shared by all Python objects? (I get some hints from here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8620be99da930230b18ec05f4d7446ee403531af/Include/object.h#L105-L109)

Comment: Yes, they are included by `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` in  `PyListObject` object.

Comment: So I guess the basically idea is that, first you create a normal list in python; after that, you emulate a C struct in python using the class with the same name, then you point an instance of the class to the beginning of the memory of the normal list, since the class (used to emulate C struct) has the same structure as the original C struct, so each variable in the instance exactly fits its corresponding element in the underlying C struct. Therefore, after some manipulation, we can print the value from the class--because all the memory blocks are matching. Is this the basic idea?

Comment: Yes, this is roughly how it works

Comment: But I do notice a special issue. In the class `PyListObject`, you actually defined a list `_fields_` (Is this simply a list of 5 tuples?). This is confusing since you need another layer of C struct to implement this list...But still it works?